# Compile error on Developer Command Prompt for VS 2019 using C++

Tags: c++, compilation

The goal is to code a simple program that reads two strings and compare them to each other. The error (C2679 binary '>>') is pointing to the input line of the code, the 'cin' line. I've done the #include and the using declaration, but maybe I am missing a notation that isn't apparent to me:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

int main(){
    
// define two strings
string s1, s2;

// read two strings
cin >> s1 >> s2 >> endl;

// compare two strings to determine if equal or report the larger
if(s1 != s2){
    if(word1 > word2)
        cout << s1 << " is larger than " << s2 << endl;
    else
        cout << s2 << " is larger than " << s1 << endl;
    
} else
    cout << "The words are equal in size" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you cannot write to `std::endl`. What should that mean?

Comment: Remove endl from the cin statement. It should be `cin >> s1 >> s2;`

Answer (score 2):

- Using `endl` with `cin` doesn't make sense. `>> endl` should be removed.
- `word1` and `word2` are not declared here. It seems `if(word1 > word2)` should be `if(s1 > s2)`.

Comment: Thank you for the catch, still learning and trying to keep it all in my head. Also appreciate the word1 and word2 correction. I had them labeled that way originally and thought maybe 'word' was what caused the error before switching to s1 and s2.